# com.facebook.widget.loginbutton error in xml

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I know as soon as I post this question on stackOverflow it is going to be marked as duplicate but trust me I have tried every possible solution discussed under the same topic in StackOverflow.

I am trying to add Facebook SDK in my project . After adding it under my project->properties->Android (then add facebook adk as library) , when i try to create my xml file and use  it shows me red cross next to it and no matter what i do I am not able to make this error go away. Please help me..Anything help is appreciated!!

Comment: use class name with your own project package instead of `com.facebook.widget` in xml for loginbutton

Comment: I don't understand exactly what do you meant by "Use class name with your own.."

Comment: If you go to Window -> Show View -> Problems. What issues show?

Comment: it says error:Error parsing XML : unbound prefix

Comment: @jimmithy Could anyone please help me in here?? Really stuck from days in this..:(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 'Unbound Prefix' error is due to having a custom namespace in your xml that is not accounted for.

You need to add another prefix to the top of your file. It should be similar to what I've wrote below, but with *PREFIX* replaced by the prefix you are using.

```
xmlns:*PREFIX*="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

So, in the end, your file should look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/connectWithFbButton"
    style="@style/com_facebook_loginview_default_style"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/connect_with_facebook"
    fb:login_text="@string/connect_with_facebook"
    fb:logout_text="Connecting with facebook" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In this example I've added the prefix 'fb' and I have referenced it when using the fields login_text and logout_text :)

Comment: I don't believe that I missed this thing..All this time I kept thinking that this problem was related to adding the FaceBook SDk..Thanks a lot!! I really appreciate it..Thanks again.:)

Comment: In Android Studio it shows me error message "Namespace 'fb' is not bound', why is that and how to solve this error? .. Thank you

Comment: Astrount: you need to add the xmlns bit to the xml tag at the top of the file first.

Answer (score 1):

use

FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

before

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Answer (score 0):

Keep both library and project in the same workspace.

Comment: They are in the same workspace..I copied Facebook SDK in workspace while importing..Thanks..Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

try to deleting this two lines
 fb:login_text="@string/connect_with_facebook"
 fb:logout_text="Connecting with facebook"